# $ABCD$ is a square, with $K$ and $L$ are points on $BC$ and $DC$ respectively . If $AM \perp LK$ AND $\angle AKM = \angle AKB$ , Find $\angle LAK$ .

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, angle, congruences-geometry

Here is a diagram if needed :- [image]

**What I Tried** :- I did angle-chasing , considered $\angle MKA = \angle AKB = x$ and then I did not get any information for some other angles , so I considered $\angle DAL$ to be $y$ . This didn't help , so overall this angle-chasing did not help . (Please don't ask me for my work in a diagram as it will take some time to send it. )

In the end, I saw that $\Delta AMK \cong \Delta ABK$ by $AAS$ congruency . This helps only a little bit as I only get to know that $AM = AB$ , nothing more .

Finally, I decided to use Geogebra to get some more information which I was missing for this Problem . There I found that $\Delta ADL \cong \Delta ALM \cong \Delta AMK \cong \Delta ABK$ , but I couldn't get it why it is so.

If I can show by some way that $\Delta ADL \cong \Delta ABK$ , then I can easily get $\angle LAK$ without any hesitation , but how will I do it?

Can anyone help?

**Edit** :- An Idea immediately struck my mind after I posted this problem (how unlucky).

I have that $\Delta AMK \cong \Delta ABK$ . This gives $AM = AB$ , and I was wrong to say that this is not a useful information .

From here I can show that $\Delta ADL \cong \Delta  AML$ by $RHS$ congruency . ($AD = AM$ since $AB = AM$ and $AB = AD$ for $AB$ and $AD$ are the side-length of the square $ABCD$ , then we have the right-angle and $AL$ is common).

So I just moved $1$ step forward . Can I move another step ?

Comment: Uh oh , I think I found some idea right now just after posting it (how unlucky) . Maybe this solves the problem , should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure - go ahead.

Comment: Okay . Posting this as an edit rather than an answer for this idea does not fully solve the Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the congruent triangles you have $\angle DAL=\angle LAM,\angle MAK=\angle KAB$.

These $4$ angles sum to $\angle DAB = 90^\circ$.

You are asked to find $\angle LAK = \angle LAM + \angle MAK$.

Comment: What you said is true , I only need to show all those $4$ triangles are congruent . How to do that? Oh I got it

Comment: You don't need to (in fact you can't).

Comment: I GET IT I GET IT , I only had to find $\angle LAK$ , which is obviously $45^{\circ}$ from your answer . I didn't realise that , I was trying to find the value of $x$ .